# Using apple script to rotate a .mov file

Tags: applescript

It's an apple scrpit question;

Running on Mac I found on the web a script that should be helpfull to rotate my MOV so they behave normally.

But I cant get it wright.

Suppose the movie that I want to work with reside here; /Users/pauldupuis/Documents/MTL/P1280602.MOV
and I want the newly rotate movie to be in the same folder /Users/pauldupuis/Documents/MTL

Can somebody fill the blanks for me and put these info in the script below so that it can work?

```
tell application "QuickTime Player"
set m to (get movie 1)
rotate m by -90
save self contained m in (choose file name with prompt "save self contained movie")
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

Paul the following is for Quicktime Player 7 which you can download for free from Apple's website.

```
tell application "QuickTime Player 7"
    tell front document

        # Get the filename
        set mName to name

        # Get the full path
        set mPath to path

        # Get the full path of the folder file is in...
        try
            set mFolder to (do shell script "dirname " & mPath)
        on error eStr
            log eStr

            beep

            # oh no, something went wrong...
            return
        end try

        # Prepare new filename
        set dotPos to offset of "." in mName
        set fName to text 1 thru (dotPos - 1) of mName
        set fExt to text (dotPos) thru -1 of mName
        log fName & " - " & fExt

        set newFile to mFolder & "/" & fName & "-rotated" & fExt


        # Do rotation       
        rotate track "Video Track" by -90

        # Save to new file...
        save self contained in (newFile as POSIX file)
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: I am a newbie in Script ed. same prob. I dont know where to put the file or the path name that i provided in the first post.

Comment: @PaulDupuis The above code assumes the file is already open. If you want to apply the rotation to say, a selected file in Finder, then you need to make an Automator Service. Is that what you want?

Comment: I wish I will not need Automatore, only applescript i will try your script and comment later on.

Comment: It seems that QuickTime 10.4 does not have a "rotate". It does not show in the `Script Editor > Open Dictionary > QuickTime Player > rotate`